# How to label multiple BoxSelectTool in bokeh?

Tags: python-3.x, bokeh, object-detection-api, labeling, bokehjs

I am trying to run a object detection labeling code. So for different objects I defined a separated Box select tool. So all of them show up at the top of the picture but you all of them have a hovering label 'box select'. How can I change that label to the category name?